# Preventing a "hidden" redirect with urlopen() in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib, urlopen

I am using **BeautifulSoup** for web scraping and I am having problems with a particular type of website when using **urlopen**. Every item on the website has its own unique page and the item comes in different formats (*ex: 500 mL, 1L, 2L,...*).

When I open the URL of the product (*www.example.com/product1*) using my Internet Browser, I would see a picture of the 500 mL format, information about it (*price, quantity, flavor, etc.*) and a list of all the other formats available for this specific item. If a click on another format (*ex: 1L*), the picture and the information about the item would change but the URL at the top of my browser would stay the same (*www.example.com/product1*). However, I know by inspecting the HTML code of the page that all the format have their own unique URL (*500 mL : www.example.com/product1/123; 1L : www.example.com/product1/456, ...*). When using the unique URL of the 1L format in my Internet Browser, I am automatically redirected to the page *www.example.com/product1* but the picture and the information displayed on the page corresponds to the 1L format. The HTML code also contains the information that I need about the 1L format.

My problem arises when I use **urlopen** to open these unique URLs.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from urllib import urlopen
webpage = urlopen('www.example.com/product1/456')
soup=BeautifulSoup(webpage)
print soup
```

The information contained in the soup **does not** correspond to the information displayed using my Internet Browser for the unique URL: *www.example.com/product1/456*. It gives me the information about the item format displayed by default on *www.example.com/product1* which is always the 500 mL format.

Is there any way I can prevent this redirection that would allow me to capture with BeautifulSoup the information contained in the HTML code of the unique URLs?

Comment: ..are you sure there aren't javascript or frames involved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import urllib2

class RedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        result = urllib2.HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, headers, fp)
        result.status = code
        return result
    http_error_301 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_302

opener = urllib2.build_opener(RedirectHandler())
webpage = opener.open('http://www.example.com/product1/456')
...
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help falsetru, I really appreciate it.