# Scrape page using Python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some problems with web scraping, here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
import re
import csv
import argparse

def save_csv_file(filename, array):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["item_name","item_price","item_category"])
        writer.writerows(array)

def process_data(name, price, category):

    item_name = name.text if name else 'NA'
    item_price = price.text if price else 'NA'
    item_category = category.text if category else 'NA'

    item_name = item_name.replace(" ", "").replace("\r\n", "").replace("\n", "").encode("utf-8")
    item_price = item_price.replace(" ", "").replace("\r\n", "").replace("\n", "").encode("utf-8")
    item_category = item_category.replace(" ", "").replace("\r\n", "").replace("\n", "").encode("utf-8")

    return (item_name, item_price, item_category)

def do_scrap(filename, url, payload, headers):

    # Request the URL with parameters and headers
    r = requests.post(url, payload, headers = headers, allow_redirects = True)

    if(r.status_code == 200):

        # Save response content in html variable
        html = r.content

        # Parsed html variable into HTML file with bs4
        parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

        # Print document title
        print parsed_html.head.find('title').text

        # Find all of the HTML elements which are describing hotels
        tables = parsed_html.find_all("a", {"class" : "result-link"})

        # Print the numbers of the hotels
        print "Found %s records." % len(tables)

        # Empty helpers
        items = []
        count = 0

        # Looping the HTML elements and print properties for each hotel
        for table in tables:
            name = table.find("h3", {"class" : "result-title"})
            price = table.find("p", {"class" : "price text-truncate"})
            category = table.find("p", {"class" : "merchant-name text-truncate"})

            items.append(process_data(name, price, category))
        count += 1

        if count > 0:
            # Save array with data to csv file
            save_csv_file(filename = filename, array = items)

            # Print end of job info
            print "\n%s records downloaded and saved to %s." % (count, filename)
    else:
        print "Code error: %s" % r.status_code

if __name__ == '__main__':

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-p","--product",required=True,help="Product name")
ap.add_argument("-c","--category",default="",help="Product category")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())

product = args['product']
category = args['category']

payload = {
    'siteSearchQuery':product,
    'from':'colibri'
}

headers = {
    'Host':'www.kelkoo.co.uk',
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language':'pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36'
}

url = "http://www.kelkoo.co.uk/ctl/do/search"

filename = "%s_co_uk_kelkoo_data.csv" % product

do_scrap(
    filename=filename,
    url=url,
    payload=payload,
    headers=headers)
```

After this request I am getting different result than I put this:

```
www.kelkoo.co.uk/ctl/do/search?siteSearchQuery=nokia+130&from=colibri
```

into my web browser, what is causing this problem? Is there is something related to page redirection or something?

Comment: If redirection is an issue, then this answer could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974321/preventing-a-hidden-redirect-with-urlopen-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see multiple things that will cause you to get different results:

- You initiate a POST not a GET. Lookup `params` for `requests.get`.
- They use javascript to modify the page.

Comment: Yeah, you are right so silly mistake ;/ I am feeling like a newbie ;) I only changed `post` to `get` and it is working perfectly.